# Prevent PuTTY from minimizing

Tags: terminal, putty, serial-port

I am using PuTTY to monitor a serial port spewing both binary data and ascii data at 1000000 baud.  The binary characters are raw uint32_t bytes from sensor values and are essentially random.  When binary data is printing funny things happen:

1. Window title changes multiple times a second
2. Colors occasionally change
3. The window will occasionally minimize.

The 3rd issue is the one I'm trying to solve.  Under Terminal->Features I have checked the boxes for

1. Disable remote-controlled terminal resizing
2. Disable switching to alternate terminal screen
3. Disable remote-controlled window title chaning

But the terminal can still minimize on it's own.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: try use http://code.google.com/p/superputty/

Comment: Are you connecting putty directly to a serial port? Or are you running a program inside putty that's spewing this data? If the latter, what is the operating system of the host that putty is connecting to?

Comment: I'm connecting putty directly to a serial port.  The host is windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Putty isn't suited to the task of monitoring arbitrary binary data. It interprets what it receives as a terminal-emulator should.

See [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-wintitle](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-wintitle)

> **A.7.12 When I cat a binary file, I get ‘PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY’ on my command line.**
>
> Don't do that, then.
>
> This is designed behaviour; when PuTTY receives the character Control-E from the remote server, it interprets it as a request to identify itself, and so it sends back the string ‘PuTTY’ as if that string had been entered at the keyboard. Control-E should only be sent by programs that are prepared to deal with the response. Writing a binary file to your terminal is likely to output many Control-E characters, and cause this behaviour. Don't do it. It's a bad plan.
>
> To mitigate the effects, you could configure the answerback string to be empty (see section 4.3.7); but writing binary files to your terminal is likely to cause various other unpleasant behaviour, so this is only a small remedy.
>
> **A.7.13 When I cat a binary file, my window title changes to a nonsense string.**
>
> Don't do that, then.
>
> It is designed behaviour that PuTTY should have the ability to adjust the window title on instructions from the server. Normally the control sequence that does this should only be sent deliberately, by programs that know what they are doing and intend to put meaningful text in the window title. Writing a binary file to your terminal runs the risk of sending the same control sequence by accident, and cause unexpected changes in the window title. Don't do it.

---

I would search for a serial-port monitor such as [portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) and use that instead.

Comment: I understand that Putty isn't designed for that, however the device I'm monitoring also sends ascii data interleaved with binary that I would like to view.  I've found settings which solve A.7.12 and A.7.13, just nothing for minimizing.